# System Processes table of Java Mission Control is empty

Tags: jmc, jfr

When I an using Flight Recorder for any server for the first time, the Processes tab under System is listing the processes. But second time onwards, for the same server the system System Processes table is empty. What do I need to do to get the proceesses every time I use Flight Recorder.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Operating System/System Process event will be emitted once per recording chunk. If that is too seldom for your use case, just enter another periodicity for the Operating System/System Process event. For example 90s.